# Lua Lanes: attempt to index global 'os' (a nil value)

Tags: lua

I wanted to use [Lua Lanes](https://github.com/LuaLanes/lanes) to do a multithreading and record the time taken. Here is the code:

```
require "lanes"

function performTest ()
    os.execute("testJson-mt.lua")
end

for i=1,10,1 do
    f= lanes.gen(performTest)
    a=f()
    startTime = os.time()
    print("ID "..a[1].." completed.")
    endTime = os.time()
    diff = os.difftime (endTime, startTime)
    print(i..","..os.date("%x %X",startTime)..","..os.date("%x %X",endTime)..","..startTime..","..endTime..","..diff)
end
```

However, when I run the code, the console returns an error: `lua: testLanes.lua:4: attempt to index global 'os' (a nil value)`.

This error code point to this line where `os.execute("testJson-mt.lua")`. I don't quite understand this error. Please advise.

Note: I am using [Lua for Windows](https://code.google.com/p/luaforwindows/) as the IDE.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By default, [`lanes.gen` loads no libraries](http://kotisivu.dnainternet.net/askok/bin/lanes/), not even base libraries. Therefore pass `'*'` as the first parameter to `lanes.gen` to get the `os` and other modules in the lane.

Comment: Marking an answer which helped you as solved would be great ;)

Comment: "*" loads all libraries which is overkill, you could just use "os" as the first parameter to lanes.gen

Comment: Technically you are correct, but in practice you'll soon need `print` (in the `base` library), some `string` processing, etc., so I usually use `'*'` at start and later tune the libraries when necessary.

Comment: I am using Lua Bridge with Lua lanes. Is there a way to copy all the mapped classes to the lua states in the lane. I get an error whenever trying to access mapped Lua object from a lane.

Answer (score 1):

You could also just do `require "os"`.

Comment: Note that this call to require would have to be inside the function `performTest()` so that it is executed in each lane rather than in the base state.